# Upper and lower limits for numbers of runs

Tags: runs

On [this website](http://thequalityweb.com/measure3.html) about statistical process control there is a chart which gives the upper and lower limits for the number of runs in a set of data for the data set to be considered taken from a process that is showing only "common cause" variation. My question: is there any theoretical justification for the limits given, or are the limits context dependent? If there is a justification I would appreciate links to further reading.